# Inverse of array implode() in php

Tags: php

Implode:

```
$array = array("text1", "text2");
echo $out = implode("-", $array);
```

Output:

```
text1-text2
```

**What I want:**

```
 $out2 = invese_implode("-", $out);
```

Out:

```
$out2 = array("text1", "text2");
```

I have tried to create a function inverse upload and made it trim the string every symbol but it doesn't worked correctly.

Comment: You mean just using `explode()`?

Comment: That's what ``explode()`` function is fotr!!

Comment: https://3v4l.org/3YKAK

Comment: Yes thank you I have tried split() also and worked.